# What OpenXava version is my project using?

Tags: openxava

In 2021 I built a project using [OpenXava](https://www.openxava.org/) and it is now in production. I forgot about it for a while, but now my customer asked me to make a few changes.
First things first, I'd like to upgrade it to the latest OpenXava release (6.6.3 as of today), but I need to know what OX release I used back then in order to follow [the correct upgrade procedure](https://www.openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/migration_en.html).

How do I tell what OX release was bundled with my project when I deployed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OpenXava application will show the OpenXava version number on startup, so you can see it in the log of Tomcat.

If you don't want to start the application and only have the WAR of your application, look for the xava-version.properties file inside openxava.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: the project workspace obviously contains the OpenXava library, which carries a `changelog.txt` file.